# Having more than one action in a webapi controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api controller and up until now it only had one action and everything was working fine. I have tried to add a second action and I cannot get it to be accessible.

Here is the method signature and snip of method body for the working action:

```
[Route("data/add")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Add(Message item)
{
    using(var ctx = new dbContext())
    {
        // add new message using EF. snip
    }
}
```

My method signature and snip of method body for the action I am having trouble with is:

```
[Route("data/check")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Check(DateTime date)
{
    using (var ctx = new dbContext())
    {
        // check if any messages after param date
        // snip
    }
}
```

And here is my route config.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Notification",
        routeTemplate: "{controller}/check"
    );
}
```

The funny thing is my other action, the one that is working, can be accessed via

> > data/add

which seems to contradict the routing.

Edit: The message I get back from Postman is

> > No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:62243/data/check'

Comment: Which version of Asp.Net are you using?

Comment: v4.0.30319 @Nikolaus

Comment: Do you have a route-Attribute on your controller too?

Comment: What happens if you remove:  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Notification",
        routeTemplate: "{controller}/check"
    );

Comment: @Nikolaus the route is in the original post

Comment: It seems no one has a definitive answer. Only solution I see is to have 1 action per controller, which is BS

Comment: once again what happens if you remove:config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( name: "Notification", routeTemplate: "{controller}/check" );

Comment: It goes into the data/add action

Comment: What is your controller declaration?

Comment: DataController : ApiController

Comment: Very strange I just tried an example just like yours. But i used GET instead of POST to better understand the problem.

Comment: The only way I could make it FAIL.... Was if i got the names of the parameters wrong when making the call.    So the names of the parameters have to be right in order for it to work

Comment: How are you calling these actions? AJAX? or a form post?

Comment: Also make sure you DO NO have a route in place. Because Attribute Routing does not require it

Comment: Leave only the default route. Please show the code that calls into these actions

Comment: Testing from Postman right now.

Comment: Can you post your webapiconfig and your controller?

Comment: public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
  
        [Route("data/add")]
        [HttpGet]
        public string Add(string item)
        {
            return item;
        }

        [Route("data/check")]
        [HttpGet]
        public string Check(string otheritem)
        {
            return otheritem;
        }


    }

Comment: public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }

Comment: Try using GET instead of post and just use the browser with query parameters and see if that helps.  I used string parameters to test easier. Just to make sure the route actually works

Comment: Did you manage to solve it yet?

Comment: Another question, that is important: Which version of WebApi do you use? 1 or 2? For this changes my next edit!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the routing to the default routing and route only via attributes like this:

```
//Add this to your Controller
[RoutePrefix("api/{controller}")]
public class YourController:ApiController
{
   //Whatever code 

   // Only part-route necessary.
   [Route("add")]
   [HttpPost]
   public HttpResponseMessage Add(Message item)
   {
       using(var ctx = new dbContext())
       {
            // add new message using EF. snip
        }
   }

   // Like before 
   [Route("check")]
   [HttpPost]
   public HttpResponseMessage Check(DateTime date)
   {
       using (var ctx = new dbContext())
       {
           // check if any messages after param date
           // snip
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you have a routeprefix defined for the Add method, and not the Check?

Comment: I don't understand: I have a RoutePrefix for the Controller and a RouteAttribute for both methods.

Comment: No. Can you post your global.asax , and your webapiconfig? If I add the routeprefix I get an error when starting the project. I have multiple controllers

Comment: @andrewb Unfortunately, I have no global.asax to provide. Did you manipulate the routing in your global.asax? What happens, if you skip the RoutePrefixAttribute, but change the routes to only the Action-names?